# Ignoring one specific or any special character while searching in pymongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

So I have some products in my mongodb which are listed below

1. Santa Claus Sweets
2. herleys sweet
3. Quality-Sweet

Now the searches which I am getting comes in the small case and maybe sometimes with special characters or no special characters. So how can I build a query which can give the output accurately? For example, if a user has entered "**quality sweet**" then it should match "**Quality-Sweet**" in my mongodb. If the user has entered "**HERLEYS SWEET**" in uppecase then it should match "**herleys sweet**" (as shown above in my MongoDB)

```
db.product.find({"Product":re.compile('^' + re.escape(pr) + '$',re.IGNORECASE)})
```

I have the above query which works with upper or lower case but if the user is searching for something like "herleys-sweet" then it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is use the `re.sub()` function to substitute special characters with something else.

You can have something like this:

```
db.product.find({"Product":re.compile('^' + re.sub('[<list of special characters>]', '<string to replace with>', pr) + '$',re.IGNORECASE)})
```

For example:

- create the list of special characters: `[\-\_\~\!\\\/\^\$\%]`
- choose what to substitute special characters with. Could be a space `' '` or anything `.*`.

Then, you would have:

```
db.product.find({"Product":re.compile('^' + re.sub('[\-\_\~\!\\\/\^\$\%]', '.*', pr) + '$',re.IGNORECASE)})
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable solution. This has resolved my problem. Qudos to you.